# show a loader for banner untill a backround images (using css) in loaded. using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a responsive banner, i have called the images as background of li tag. I want to show a loader until all the images are loaded as background and display the banner .

Thanks

Comment: http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jpreloader-a-preloading-screen-to-preload-images/

Comment: hi caramba. how can i add jpreloader only to the banner. I don't want the entair website to preload.

Answer (score 0):

you can set an image or everything you want, on the top of the form by default, and assign a handler to the `load` event of the `body` element like this: `<body onload="WindlowLoadHandler()">`, this handler is called when all of the assets in your form be loaded, and in this handler, you can hide the image (or everything) have been shown by default